# Set fields based on ComboBox Value Java

Tags: java, jtextfield, jcombobox

I'm trying to retrieve data from the database and set jTextFields automatically.

Ive managed to retrieve the table column for the Name and set it to the `combobox`.

But now I want everything related to the selected item to show up automatically in the jTextfields.

I tried the following code but have an error on `setString` not being recognised:

```
    private void jComboBox1PopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                        
        String tmp = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        String SQL = "select * from ROOT.\"Books\" WHERE Name=?";

         try{
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/books";
    String userName = "root";
    String Pass = "1234";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, userName, Pass); 
    Statement stmnt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    stmnt.setString(1, tmp);
     ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(SQL);

     if (rs.next()) 
        {
            String add1 = rs.getString("Year");
            jTextField1.setText(add1);
            String add2 = rs.getString("Price");
            jTextField2.setText(add2);
        }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    }
```

Comment: "does not work" is not a problem statement. Please be as specific as possible when describing what is going wrong.

Comment: `Am getting error here:` again getting an error means nothing to us. We are NOT mind readers. We don't know what kind of error you are getting.  Fix your code and use an ActionLIstener as suggested. You probably don't have a selected item when the popup is displayed. If you still have a problem, update the question with the proper code.

Comment: Well `setString(int, String)` doesn't exist in the `Statement` class... Perhaps you meant [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: @Obicere how do i fix this

Comment: @JamesSmith to be honest I have no idea. Never used this stuff before, just did a google search. Maybe try `PreparedStatement stmnt = (PreparedStatement) con.createStatement();`.

Comment: Connection.prepareStatement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can say, is don't use a PoupMenuListener.

You should be using and `ActionLIstener` or an `ItemListener` to handle the event when the user make a selection from the combo box.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Well i took the code out and set it to its own method and still wouldnt populate.

Comment: @JamesSmith, not idea what your above comment means. You still haven't described your problem. Is the problem the SQL, the query or what. Fix your question and read the tutorial and start with a working example.